# JQuery Timeline Widget

Tags: calendar, jquery, widget

I'm looking for a Timeline type widget that I can embed in a web application.  I'd like to have the time line display at several different granularities (e.g. Year, Month, Day, Hour etc.).  It would be great if the mouse wheel could be used to change the granularity so that you can zoom in from year to month to day etc.

I'd also be able to highlight points on the timeline where an event occurred so a user could select the event.

Something similar to the below would be ideal:
https://www.dropcam.com/live-demos/attractions/cheetah-den-at-the-metro-richmond-zoo